# Why navigation bar drop down menu doesn't align vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's the code:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwbdq53u/4/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../test.css">
    <title>Test title</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav id="user-nav">
      <div id="logo-container">
        <a href="#index.php" class="link-dec"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Loading logo"></a>
        <p>This is a site</p>
      </div>
      <div id="form-container">
        <i id="search-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="form-search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Quick search...">
      </div>
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#index.php" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        <a href="#Browse" class="nav-link">Services</a>
        <a href="#request" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-link">
        <a href="#profile" class="user-link">Profile name</a>
        <div class="drop-menu">
          <a href="#buy">Switch</a>
          <a href="#logout">Log out</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>

  </body>

</html>
```

and CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

#user-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 62px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#logo-container img {
  width: 96px;
  height: 60px;
}

#logo-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.profile-link {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
}

.drop-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px;
  background: #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I removed all extra css from other elements in navbar because i thought it was affecting the last divs but it didn't affect the misalignment. I tried different display properties for the div that holds profile name even using list instead of div for drop-down-menu, i always get this offset of 1px. I am styling the navbar using flex because i want to make it more responsive, i am not sure is this somehow affecting the issue.

Comment: You use `position: absolute` for `.drop-menu` and it made `.drop-menu`  fall out from normal flow. Therefore flex doesn't affect on `.drop-menu`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I actually fixed it since it was offseting to the right i added `right: 0` and now it's aligned.